# Laravel schedule: cron job special characters not allowed

Tags: cron, scheduler, laravel-6

I'm trying to add a cron job on a shared hosting like this

```
/usr/bin/php /home/USER/public_html/LARAVEL_PROJECT/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The support confirmed the path and command is correct but they don't allow special characters in the command so I have to remove `>> /dev/null 2>&1` and that doesn't make it work. Any work around?

Answer (score 2):

You can create own shell script, add there the entire command (with redirection) and ask to add this shell file in to the `cron`

You can create the script to be: `/home/USER/script.sh` and to contain

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php /home/USER/public_html/LARAVEL_PROJECT/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Then you need to make it executable (via ssh for example)

```
chmod +x /home/USER/script.sh
```

or

```
chmod 750 /home/USER/script.sh
```

And then ask support to run this script instead of your line.

Comment: Any guide please? I don't know how to do that.